# Xtext maven build with project wizard of example project

Tags: maven, xtext, tycho

Hello I tried to build the example xtext project via maven by using the project wizard, adding feature and update site and choosing maven build. To overcome another error I changed Tycho version to 2.3.0 . I now get the following build error I just cant get rid of:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (mwe2Launcher) @ org.xtext.example.mydsl ---
0    [org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main()] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:507)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.Mwe2StandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjector(Mwe2StandaloneSetupGenerated.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.Mwe2StandaloneSetupGenerated.createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration(Mwe2StandaloneSetupGenerated.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I changed the version of the coresponding exec-maven-plugin but didnt help. Any idea? And maybe an generic idea how to debug that kind of errors? Thank you!

Comment: what is the complete error you get? can you compare your project with what the Xtext 2.26.0.M2 Wizard creates? also make sure you dont use Java 17 to run the build (works with the mentioned milestone only)

Comment: I tried the exact same configuration with another laptop - it worked, so I will go with that, thank you!

Comment: maybe you have something wrong in your local maven repo